# Re using the dialog component in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-components

> **Scenario:**

I have 2 json files called `customers` and `workers`:

**customers:**

```
[
    {
        "cusId": "01",
        "customerName": "Customer One",
        "email": "customer1@email.com"
    },
    {
        "cusId": "02",
        "customerName": "Customer Two",
         "email": "customer2@email.com"
    },
    {
        "cusId": "03",
        "customerName": "Customer Three",
        "email": "customer3@email.com"
    }
]
```

**workers:**

```
[
    {
        "workId": "01",
        "workerName": "worker One",
        "email": "worker1@email.com"
    },
    {
        "workId": "02",
        "workerName": "worker Two",
         "email": "worker2@email.com"
    },
    {
        "workId": "03",
        "workerName": "worker Three",
        "email": "worker3@email.com"
    }
]
```

When i want to delete an **particular object** in the **customers** json i will inject particular object to `dialog component` called **delete**. And in the template i will show the property name(Ex "customerName) as in the below code(delete component):

```
<p>Do you want to delete <span>{{data.customerName}}</span></p>
```

So that user can see that which object he is deleting. The UI looks like this for `customers` object:

[image]

But for the `workers` object the property name changes to **workerName**,Now i am display only the message not the property name(ie workerName) in the dialog window:

[image]

> **Requirement:**

- Along with the message,I want display the both **property** names of `customers` and `workers` **without changing the property name in the two JSON files**.And the UI should look like this:

For customers:

[image]

For workers:

[image]

- Now i am injecting the whole object to **delete** component, Instead of that i want to emit only **Id**, **Name** property(Ex customerName,workerName) to the delete component.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-dvu69v?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: There are some another errors in the console

Comment: The error comes because you are clicking `delete` button without selecting/clicking the  `customer/worker`.

Comment: First you click any `customer/worker`, then click the `delete` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only two types of JSON objects you can try this method -

```
{{data.customerName || data.workerName}}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-ugycua?file=src/app/delete/delete.component.html)

PS: But if you have multiple different keys to use in dialog component, I would recommend better to pass customized object data when you pass data to the dialog component in order to avoid this `||` (conditional), operators.
like below -

```
public openDialogDelete($event: ICustomer): void {
const dataToShow = {id: "000", name: "Name here", email: "Email@gmail.com"}
  const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteComponent> = this.dialog.open(DeleteComponent, {
    width: '360px', disableClose: false, data: dataToShow,
});
```

Comment: Actually i am re using the `delete` component in the whole app, I am re using it many times.The proprty names changes to different api's.

Comment: @Empty_Soul check my updated answer

Comment: I know  that i should pass `customized object` if want to reuse the component, but i didn't found  any resources to `inject` the `customized object` to the component..

Comment: @Empty_Soul like above in example

Comment: Let me try ..:)

Comment: Sorry to ask this:  In this line you are setting hardcoded data **const dataToShow = {id: "000", name: "Name here", email: "Email@gmail.com"}**, Instead of that how can i send the JSON(ine customerName, Id properties) data?

Comment: haha @Empty_Soul NP, Instead of setting Hardcode, you need to get data via params, the way you are getting before and create a new object using that data and pass to dialogcomponent. I hope this clears everything.